# gap.barplot error bars not plotting

Tags: plotrix

I am desperately trying to find a way to plot custom error bars in gap.plot.
I used the code below but it is not working. 
Thank you

```
b <- t(matrix( c(50.84033606,119.3277309,452.1008396,1971.0084,
                2734.033609,115.1260502,239.0756299,569.7478983,1949.579829,
                2607.983189),
              nrow=5, ncol=2 ))

b=rbind(NA,d)

require(plotrix)

a <- gap.barplot(as.matrix(b), 
                gap=c(850,1600), 
                ytics=c(0,300,2000,2500),
                ylab = "",
                xlab = "",
                xaxt='n',
                pch=20,
                las= 2,
                xlim = c(0,18),
                ylim = c(0,2750),
                col=rep(c(grey.colors(2), 1), 6))
abline(h=seq(840,950), col="white") 

axis.break(2, 850, style = "slash", brw = 0.060)
b2<- c(50.84033606,119.3277309,452.1008396,1971.0084,
       2734.033609,115.1260502,239.0756299,569.7478983,1949.579829,
       2607.983189)
se<- as.matrix(c(6.522762467,11.72524894,10.60456256,57.25512628,57.09610968,
                 5.388972823,16.50463808,24.69269495,64.07253048,129.4765469))
segments(a, d2 - se, a, d2 + se, lwd=1) 
segments(a - 0.1, d2 - se, a + 0.1, d2 - se, lwd=1) 
segments(a - 0.1, d2 + se, a + 0.1, d2 + se, lwd=1)
```